# Prompt user after while loop and based on the users answer make a variable equal to a value (javascript)

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, while-loop, command-prompt

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var answer = prompt("Enter A or B");
var x = 0;
while (var x < 1) {
 if (answer = "A") {
  var y = 10;
  x = x+1
 } else if (answer = "B")) {
  alert("type A next time")
 } else {
  alert("Please enter A or B") ;
 }
}
var z = var y + 1
</script>
```

THis does not seem to be work as I am not even make into the loop I do not think. My end goal is to get the user to enter a value in the prompt - if they picking A then a variable y becomes 10 and the loop ends, if B is enter the user is returning to the start of the loop and the same can be said if the user does not even enter the right value (not A or B).

Thanks in advance and sorry for bad english!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `if (answer = "A") {` and `} else if (answer = "B")) {`

To `if (answer == "A") {` and `} else if (answer == "B")) {`

Comment: Oh sorry I realise i have another problem with else clause, it is not going back to prompt like I want. Should I put prompt in while loop?

Comment: I figure it out and move prompt into while loop and it seem to be work now - this is right?

Comment: @user3614034 by the sounds of it, yes this is right!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the script runs?If yes you have to change some thinks:

- in the while loop leave out the 'var' in 'var x < 1' at the moment you create a new variable.
- in the if statements use '==' instead.  '=' changes the value '==' compares.
- instead of 'var z= var y + 1' use 'var z = y +1'

Comment: Yes sorry I did do that I notice there is a problem, after else clause it does not return it to start of loop instead it keeps showing alert. How do I fix? By this I mean I want prompt to show again - do I put it in while loop?

Comment: @user3614034 1. You have some ';' missing for example here: 'x = x+1'. Moreover after that line x is 1 so x isn't < 1 so the while loop doesent loops a second time.

Comment: Also I think a alert freezes the script. Not sure though.